# False induction proof about filling a $2^n \times 2^n$ region using a 3 tile shape

Tags: induction, fake-proofs

I already have a proven claim to prove that a $2^n \times 2^n$ courtyard can be filled with L-shaped tiles with a centre tile available to install a statue (of a wealthy donor "Bill" in this half-true story).

[image]

---

Now, I am attempting the below problem (taken from free textbook: Mathematics for Computer Science textbook from MIT):

[image]
[image]

---

Where is the theorem wrong? Why doesn't the argument made in the first problem apply to the second one?

- I found the base case, OK.
- I was thinking whether the odd shape of the second problem would make building the inductive hypothesis difficult. But I cannot really see why the hypothesis as stated can be argued to be false.
- Is it the case that for this problem, a stronger hypothesis (which was necessary for solving first problem) is not a valid one?

Comment: You merely used images to present the question.

Comment: sorry, the question is lengthy. It is taken from a free textbook, so no copyright issues (I will add a citation). But the last paragraph explains my thoughts.

Comment: Try going through the induction step with some concrete (small) numbers, like $P(0)\to P(1)$ or $P(1)\to P(2)$. Do you notice anything that doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks, senseiwu.  No problems

Comment: @StefanAlbrecht That was a great hint indeed!! Simple for a novice to overlook